# Salesforce Strange Screen when Login

Tags: login-errors, platform-bug

Today I saw a strange screen when tried to login to Salesforce environment. I seems like a server default page. But curious to know if someone has seen this screen previously.

In addition I am little bit concerned that my customer wouldn't see this screen as it is unexpected.

Probably it can be issue in our internal network but we don't use *skuid/3.2.3*

[image]

**Update:**

When pinging the IP provided in error message it fails with same connection timed out message in command prompt.

[image]

Comment: Squid is a Web cache/proxy:  http://www.squid-cache.org it will most likely be at your end but I have seen some smaller isps use it as well (I'm seen the screen when browsing on my mobile for example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be something on your end.  182.50.78.61 and it resolved   to https://ap2.salesforce.com/

IP  :   182.50.78.61        Neighborhood
Host    :   login-tyo.g.salesforce.com    OK
Country :   Singapore

also http://trust.salesforce.com/trust/instances/AP2 did not show any issues today.